# Codeigniter newline for email does not work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, newline

When I try to send email with Codeigniter email is not send with newlines. I tried some of tecniques written stackoverflow but not worked.

Here is my codes :

```
 $message = 'Hi everyone\r\n';
 $message .= 'Today you can look at these sites\r\n';
 $message .= 'Have a good days';

 $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
 $config['mailtype'] = 'text';
 $config['newline'] = '\r\n';

 $this->load->library('email');
 $this->email->initialize($config);
 $this->email->from('xxxxx@xxx.com');
 $this->email->to('aaaa@aaaaaa.com');

 $this->email->subject('Today New Sites');
 $this->email->message($message);
 $this->email->send();
```

I tried those also :

```
1.instead of putting \r\n, I put only \n and changed $config['newline'] = '\n'
2.I tried $this->email->message(nl2br($message));
3.I tried : str_replace('\r\n','"\r\n",$message);
4.I get rid of $config['mailtype']
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use double-quotes `"` instead of single-quotes `'`. This way the newline `\n` will work.

Answer (score 3):

Change `$config['mailtype'] = 'html';` and use `<br/>`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But while setting mailtype text, why does not it work? Any idea

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted. `$config['mailtype'] = 'html';` renders the body as `html`.